# Runtime ImportModule Error on AWS Lambda is encountered in CI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, nuxt.js

This is the full message of the runtime error:

```
2023-09-07T02:24:48.345Z    undefined   ERROR   Uncaught Exception  
{
    "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
    "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'aws-serverless-express'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/app.js\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
    "stack": [
        "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'aws-serverless-express'",
        "Require stack:",
        "- /var/task/app.js",
        "- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
        "    at _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1061:17)",
        "    at async UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1093:21)",
        "    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1256:23)",
        "    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1262:1"
    ]
}
```

Though it's included in packages.json and packages-lock.json. I even hardcoded in the ci.yml (see image below) to install the said module but still it's not reflecting.
[image]